# Remove docker container at the end of each test

Tags: docker, protractor, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-grid

I'm using docker to scale the test infrastructure / browsers based on the number of requests received in Jenkins.

Created a python script to identify the total number of spec files and browser type, and spin-up those many docker containers. Python code has the logic to determine how many nodes are currently in use, stale and it determines the required number of containers.

I want to programmatically delete the container / de-register the selenium node at the end of each spec file (Docker `--rm` flag is not helping me).So that the next test will get a clean browser and environment.

The selenium grid runs on the same box where Jenkins is. Once I invoke protractor protractor.conf.js (Step 3), selenium grid will start distributing the tests to the containers created in Step 1.

When I say '--rm' is not helping, I mean the after step3 the communication is mainly between selenium hub and the nodes. I'm finding it difficult to determine  which node / container was used by the selenium grid to execute the test and remove the container even before the grid sends another test to the container.

-- Jenkins Build Stage --
Shell:

```
   # Step 1
   python ./create_test_machine.py ${no_of_containers} # This will spin-up selenium nodes

   # Step 2
   npm install  # install node modules

   # Step 3
   protractor protractor.conf.js # Run the protractor tests
```

--Python code to spin up containers - create_test_machine.py--

Python Script:

```
import sys
import docker
import docker.utils
import requests
import json
import time

c = docker.Client(base_url='unix://var/run/docker.sock', version='1.23')
my_envs = {'HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_ADDR' :'172.17.0.1', 'HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_PORT' : 4444}

def check_available_machines(no_of_machines):   
    t = c.containers()
    noof_running_containers = len(t)
    if noof_running_containers == 0:
        print("0 containers running. Creating " + str(no_of_machines) + "new containers...")
        spinup_test_machines(no_of_machines)
    else:       
        out_of_stock = 0
        for obj_container in t:
            print(obj_container)
            container_ip_addr = obj_container['NetworkSettings']['Networks']['bridge']['IPAddress']
            container_state = obj_container['State']        
            res = requests.get('http://' + container_ip_addr + ':5555/wd/hub/sessions')         
            obj = json.loads(res.content)           
            node_inuse = len(obj['value'])
            if node_inuse != 0: 
                noof_running_containers -= 1
        if noof_running_containers < no_of_machines:
            spinup_test_machines(no_of_machines - noof_running_containers)
    return      

def spinup_test_machines(no_of_machines):
    '''
        Parameter : Number of test nodes to spin up 
    '''
    print("Creating " + str(no_of_machines) + " new containers...")
    # my_envs = docker.utils.parse_env_file('docker.env')

    for i in range(0,no_of_machines):
        new_container = c.create_container(image='selenium/node-chrome', environment=my_envs)
        response = c.start(container=new_container.get('Id'))
        print(new_container, response)
    return

if len(sys.argv) - 1 == 1:
    no_of_machines = int(sys.argv[1]) + 2   
    check_available_machines(no_of_machines)
    time.sleep(30)
else:
    print("Invalid number of parameters")
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on `--rm` is not helping you?

Comment: what's the error ? you start your container with detached mode ?

Comment: Added more info to my question. Yes, the containers are started in detached mode

Comment: I believe that it `--rm` and `-d` can't be used together. Would you please show the command that you are using to start and error that you are facing latest?

Comment: @Rao, you are correct. I tried with --rm flag but it didn't work. The above python code creates the container in detached mode only.

Comment: Wouldn't selenium hub try to keep using the nodes you create for other tests?

Answer (score 1):

Here the difference can be seen clearly when `docker run` with `-d` and `--rm`

Using `-d`option

```
C:\Users\apps>docker run -d --name testso alpine /bin/echo 'Hello World'
5d447b558ae6bf58ff6a2147da8bdf25b526bd1c9f39117498fa017f8f71978b
```

Check the logs

```
C:\Users\apps>docker logs testso
'Hello World'
```

Check the last run containers

```
C:\Users\apps>docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS               NAMES
5d447b558ae6        alpine              "/bin/echo 'Hello Wor"   35 hours ago        Exited (0) 11 seconds ago                       testso
```

Finally user have to remove it explicity

```
C:\Users\apps>docker rm -f testso
testso
```

Using `--rm`, the container is vanished including its logs as soon as the process that is
run inside the container is completed. No trace of container any more.

```
C:\Users\apps>docker run --rm --name testso alpine /bin/echo 'Hello World'
'Hello World'

C:\Users\apps>docker logs testso
Error: No such container: testso

C:\Users\apps>docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
```

I believe that it is clear, how to run the container and leaving no trace after process is finished inside of container.

Answer (score 1):

so to start a container in detached mode, you use -d=true or just -d option. By design, containers started in detached mode exit when the root process used to run the container exits. A container in detached mode cannot be automatically removed when it stops, this means you cannot use the --rm option with -d option.

look at this

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/

Answer (score 1):

You can use nose test. For every *"def test_xxx()"*, it will call the setup and teardown functions with @with_setup decrator. Below is an example:

```
from nose.tools import *

c = docker.Client(base_url='unix://var/run/docker.sock', version='1.23')
my_envs = {'HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_ADDR' :'172.17.0.1', 'HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_PORT' : 4444}

my_containers = {}

def setup_docker():
    """ Setup Test Environment, 
        create/start your docker container(s), populate the my_containers dict.
    """

def tear_down_docker():
    """Tear down test environment.
    """
    for container in my_containers.itervalues():
        try:
            c.stop(container=container.get('Id'))
            c.remove_container(container=container.get('Id'))
        except Exception as e:
            print e

@with_setup(setup=setup_docker, teardown=tear_down_docker)
def test_xxx():
    # do your test here
    # you can call a subprocess to run your selenium
```

Or, you write a separate python script to detect the containers you set up for your test, and then do something like this:

```
for container in my_containers.itervalues():
        try:
            c.stop(container=container.get('Id'))
            c.remove_container(container=container.get('Id'))
        except Exception as e:
            print e
```